# Visual Studio Code: Go - After a reformat, tabs settings are not effective

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, indentation

After having some trouble with my settings for **Golang**, only about the tabs, I found a solution, but now, after formatting my code, **VSCode** return to the previous behaviour.

I want my tabs to be **4 SPACES ONLY**, not the *tab* character.

Here is a part of my setting:

```
"editor.tabCompletion": true,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"editor.tabSize": 4,
// Insert spaces when pressing Tab.
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
"go.formatOnSave": false,
"[go]": {
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true
},
"markdownlint.config": {
    "default": true,
    "MD033": false
}
```

Follow the link to see the image before the re-format

[image]

Here is the image after the re-format

[image]

My status bar before and after the re-format keeps the same:

[image]

And my installed extensions, just in case it's an extension issue:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The default rules of [`gofmt`](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) implies using tabs for identation. I believe you can change that, but I'd strongly suggest to stick to the default formatting rules else your code will be a mess to merge with other Go code that follow the default rules.

Comment: Thanks @icza, I'm just starting to learn Golang and, before VSCode, I'm using Jetbrains Goland which have a re-format without this behavior.
So I'll keep for Go the tab and for the others (html, php, python, ...) spaces.
Now I need to find how ;-P

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
I work on macOS and have to install gnu-sed from terminal: ***brew install gnu-sed***

Install [Run On Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.run-on-save) extension.

Edit settings.json. My settings:

```
{
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "python.pythonPath": "/anaconda2/bin/python",
    "[go]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    },
    "runOnSave.statusMessageTimeout": 3000,
    "runOnSave.commands": [
        {
            "match": ".*\\.go",
            "notMatch": "",
            "command": "gsed -i 's|\\t|    |g' ${file}",
            "runIn": "backend"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use just sed command on Linux and something like this on Windows.
Be aware gsed must be available. $PATH should be updated to find it.
Also, "runIn" property can be set in "terminal" to make sure everything works properly.